# [Como verificar se a minha frase possui UMA PALAVRA OU OUTRA em Pyton]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Queria fazer algo tipo assim, para ele detectar se exista uma palavra ou outra: [inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iPu2.png)

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8702/112052

Comment: O pior é que não era isso que eu tinha em mente, era tipo assim: eu tenho um campo de input e eu escrevo: Ola bom dia, como vai.  E queria fazer ele testar se no input contem a palavra "bom dia" ou "como vai", porém no input não pode estar contendo só a palavra "bom dia" e fim, entendeu?

Comment: Se não é isso, basta [edit] a pergunta e colocar exatamente o que deveria ser `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Primeiramente, para conseguir respostas mais claras sugiro que você faça suas perguntas inserindo o trecho de código ao invés de fotos do código, pois isso agiliza o processo de revisão e análise de quem está provendo suporte.

Em segundo lugar, creio que a sua lógica tem um pequeno erro: você está checando se `lista` está `in` "bom dia", por exemplo. Para que essa condição retorne verdadeiro, o usuário poderia inserir qualquer letra ou sílaba presente em "bom dia", entende?

Creio que o que você deseja verificar é se "bom dia" está presento no input do usuário, logo:

```
palavras_alvo = ['bom dia', 'como vai']

lista = str(input("como vai você?"))

for palavra in palavras_alvo:
  if palavra in lista:
    print("existe")
```

Comment: Desculpe sou novo aqui no stackoverflow, mas era exatamente isso que eu precisava, ajudou muito. Obrigado!

Comment: Tudo bem, sem problemas! A indicação é mais para que você possa encontrar respostas mais claras e mais rapidamente nas suas próximas perguntas.

Comment: `input` já retorna uma string, então `str(input())` é desnecessário. Usar apenas `input` é o suficiente

Comment: Olá, Lucas. Notei que você está animado para ajudar, mas ao mesmo tempo está com uma série de postagens negativadas e/ou sinalizadas. Para entender melhor o o feedback desfavorável, é importante entender o objetivo do site, que é ter perguntas que sirvam para um público amplo, não só para o autor. Responder coisas com problema acaba "contaminando" a resposta (nestes casos ainda dá pra ajudar, mas recomenda-se o campo de comentários). A sugestão nesses casos é ajudar o autor a produzir um [mcve] nos casos de código ANTES de postar respostas, e evitar postagens com printscreen e negativos.

Comment: Vou deixar alguns links que servem de partida para escolher o que responder, potencializando sua boa vontade e fazendo o esforço ajudar muito mais gente de uma vez só - não desanime, negativos são só classificação dos posts - lá vai: [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70), [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70), [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/70) e até [Porque não é obrigatório comentar ao dar um negativo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8788/70) - Espero que isso ajude a "reverter o gráfico" :D

Comment: Obrigado, @Bacco!